# Who has the strongest power level according to Child Emperor's Okame-chan device?

Tags: one-punch-man

Child Emperor has a mask shaped device which allows him to measure the physical strenght of their opponents. According to it, he's physically stronger than a bear.

Who has the strongest power level according to Child Emperor's Okame-chan device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The wiki lists all measurements made](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Okame-Chan).

The device was calibrated to measure the C-class hero Red Muffler at a value of 100.  It does not read levels below 0 or above 9999.

The highest successful reading it provided of a hero was for [Great Philosopher](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Philosopher) at 2442.

The highest reading listed for anything at all was for the monster [Jumping Spider](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Jumping_Spider), at a value of 6999.  Child Emperor places this rating at a disaster level of Demon.

However, he soon realizes the device is essentially useless in practice.  It doesn't measure esper powers, for example. Fubuki just measures at 19, a roughly normal fit human reading, apparently.  King and Genos both fail to produce a reading; King because Child Emperor supposes he's clearly going to be above 9999, and Genos because he's mostly a machine.  Reading Saitama seems to break the device and yields an undefined reading, which Child Emperor interprets as meaning that Saitama is weak.  And the aforementioned jumping spider originally only read at a level of 402, because he scanned the wrong part of the monster essentially.  As such he quickly dismisses it as nothing more than an entertaining bauble, and we haven't seen it since.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with Okame Chan is that it's very limited in what it can measure. So it'd measure Tatsumaki, King, Drive Knight and Genos as 0 -- well, as unmeasurable as Child Emperor didn't think to include a less than 1 or more than 9,999 reading in his device output, leading to some hilarious misunderstandings. That three of the four above-named heroes could pop your head like a zit is neither here nor there. Come to think of it, Dr. Bofoi would probably be a zero too as a middle-aged man who doesn't work out. Maybe even Zombieman depending on how 'alive' Okame Chan thinks he is.